Does eclipse mat analyzer loads all the heap dump in memory (instead of lazy loading) to analyse?
I was using Eclipse mat analyzer to analyse a heap dump which is 32Gigs, however the memory of my remote machine is 8 Gigs and the Harddisk is 256 Gigs. When I am trying to open the heap dump I get the error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
